# Typescript interface as function return type

Tags: typescript, casting

new to Typescript here. I got a question about Typescript using interface as a function return type. I got this interface

```
interface IPerson { 
    name: string,
    age: number
}
```

If I assign an object to it, it will check the type and reject if type not match. Like

```
const person: IPerson = { name: 'Tom', age: '26' };
```

But if I use it as a return type of a function, it seems like it will not check the type

```
const personJSON = '{ "name": "Jack", "age": "30"}';

const getPersonFromJSON = <IPerson>(json) : IPerson => {
    return JSON.parse(json);
}

console.log(getPersonFromJSON(personJSON));
```

Looks like the return value willing to accept String to age.

```
{ name: 'Jack', age: '30' }
```

Wondering what I did wrong. Many thanks

Comment: `<IPerson>(json)` <-- what's this?

Comment: Ow, it is just a ES6 style I believe. You can see it as
function getPersonFromJSON<IPerson>(json) : IPerson {...}

Comment: @Miuid I understand what arrow functions are, I'm asking why that anonymous function is generic?

Comment: TypeScript does not provide run time type checking, only compile time. Since the return type of `JSON.parse` is `any` and the input is a string that can contain anything (including) invalid JSON there is no why to infer this during compile time.

Comment: @zerkms That maybe the part that I am missing. I am not too sure either. I guess what I want to achieve is a function that return an IPerson type.

Comment: @Miuid then see my answer, but as Leon mentioned - there is still no runtime check and you can pass any <del>valid JSON</del> garbage. (PS: I'm giving up, comments here don't support striking through)

Comment: I see, thanks @zerkms

Comment: And also many thanks @Leon

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
const getPersonFromJSON = <IPerson>(json) : IPerson => {
    return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

this is identical to

```
const getPersonFromJSON = <T>(json) : T => {
    return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

and defines a generic function. So effectively it's `<any>(json: any): any`

You should declare it as

```
const getPersonFromJSON = (json) : IPerson => {
    return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

instead.

References:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html